# Loop over columns in a dataframe to produce histograms by category

Tags: pandas, loops, matplotlib, histogram

I would like to investigate the frequency distribution of all the features (columns) in my df based on the outcome variable (target column). Having searched the solutions, I find this beautiful snippet from [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/dive-into-pca-principal-component-analysis-with-python-43ded13ead21) which loop over features and generate histograms for features in the cancer dataset from Scikit-learn.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
# from matplotlib.pyplot import matplotlib
fig,axes =plt.subplots(10,3, figsize=(12, 9)) # 3 columns each containing 10 figures, total 30 features
malignant=cancer.data[cancer.target==0] # define malignant
benign=cancer.data[cancer.target==1] # define benign
ax=axes.ravel()# flat axes with numpy ravel
for i in range(30):
  _,bins=np.histogram(cancer.data[:,i],bins=40)
  ax[i].hist(malignant[:,i],bins=bins,color='r',alpha=.5)
  ax[i].hist(benign[:,i],bins=bins,color='g',alpha=0.3)
  ax[i].set_title(cancer.feature_names[i],fontsize=9)
  ax[i].axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False) # the x-axis co-ordinates are not so useful, as we just want to look how well separated the histograms are
  ax[i].set_yticks(())
ax[0].legend(['malignant','benign'],loc='best',fontsize=8)
plt.tight_layout()# let's make good plots
plt.show()
```

[image: Frequency distribution of features by class]

Assuming that I have df with all features and target variable organised across successive columns, how would I be able to loop over my columns to reproduce histograms. One solution that I have considered is a `groupby` method.

```
df.groupby("class").col01.plot(kind='kde', ax=axs[1])
```

Any ideas are much appreciated!

Comment: What's wrong with the included solution?

Comment: I cannot assign custom color for different class categories. Would it be possible to tweak the loop snippet so it would be applicable to my df structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can use `sns.FacetGrid` for this:

```
# Random data:
np.random.seed(1)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(0,1,(100,6)), columns=list('ABCDEF'))
df['class'] = np.random.choice([0,1], p=[0.3,0.7], size=len(df))

# plot
g = sns.FacetGrid(df.melt(id_vars='class'), 
                  col='variable', 
                  hue='class',
                  col_wrap=3)                # change this to your liking
g = g.map(sns.kdeplot, "value", alpha=0.5)
```

Output:

[image]